# Uniquely identifying the user in the Android application via the Play store?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

I have an android application that does not have login / register structure but users can start subscription with in-app purchase.

I want to be able to recognize the user on different devices where the user logs in with the same play store account. So I want to be able to uniquely identify a user through the play store account.

Since my application is in the child and family category, I cannot access AccountManager-style sensitive data.

How can I do that. Does anyone have great ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great library which I hope will help you solve your problem as I'm already using it in some products.
You can try [This library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

This library perfectly handles `Subscriptions` as well as `Purchases` with and without payload. you just have to place `implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'` in your `build.gradle` and you are good to go.

When your `build.gradle` is ready, implement `BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler` with your `activity`.

Then intialize your billing processor by placing this code in `onCreate`.

```
bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "YOUR LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE", this);
bp.initialize();
```

You will get the following `override` methods,

```
  @Override
  public void onBillingInitialized() {
    /*
    * Called when BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to purchase 
    */
  }
    
  @Override
  public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    /*
    * Called when requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased
    */
  }
    
  @Override
  public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
    /*
    * Called when some error occurred. See Constants class for more details
    * 
    * Note - this includes handling the case where the user canceled the buy dialog:
    * errorCode = Constants.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED
    */
  }
    
  @Override
  public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
    /*
    * Called when purchase history was restored and the list of all owned PRODUCT ID's 
    * was loaded from Google Play
    */
  }
```

Here is the trick, `onPurchaseHistoryRestored` is the actual method you are looking for. This method will get called whenever there is a `subscription` or `purchase` already available against a specific email. This library will automatically handle it for you. Let me know if it help you.

Don't forget to add this `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` permission in your `Manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the subscription status of users who log in to the same account on different devices, you can use the **BillingClient.queryPurchases()** interface to query the subscription status. If the interface returns a subscription, it is within the subscription validity period, and you need to continue providing services.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not the question :(